# When checking whether a formula is a logical consequence of a set of premises, is it always necessary to check whether the set is satisfiable before?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

(Propositional logic problem):

Lets say that I have to decide whether this formula B really is a logical consequence of a set of premises {A, ¬A∨B}. Formally written: {A, ¬A∨B}⊧B . To find out, I can can reduce it to a problem of whether this formula is a tautology: (A∧(¬A∨B))⇒B. If this formula is a tautology, it means that formula B is a logical consequence of the premises. But it is possible that the premises are unsatisfiable (=they have no model). In that case anything could be a logical consequence.

I can also reduce the problem of whether B is a logical consequence of premises {A, ¬A∨B} to a problem of whether formula A∧(¬A∨B)∧¬B is unsatifiable. If the formula is unsatifiable it means that the formula B is a consequence. If the premises are unsatifiable the formula B will be a logical consequence and any other formula as well.

My question is: Is it always necessary to check whether a set of premises are satifiable in order to find out whether the formula really flows from these premises? In my textbook they never check whether premises are satifiable and just solve whether the problem reduced to previous problems is a tautology/contradiction. Because of my textbook I am confused if it is always really necessary (because it takes time to check if premises are satifiable).

Comment: It is never necessary : it can however simplify matters, e.g. if the premises are unsatisfiable then anything follows from them. But you don't have to check whether or not they are

Comment: But this deduction then would be meaningless right? In order to not be meaningless I should always check whether it is satifiable before, right?

Comment: Who says that deductions have to be meaningful? Actually, with that logic, no mathematics is meaningful, as the satisfiability of a set of premises strong enough to form a foundation of mathematics (such as $\mathsf{ZFC}$) cannot be proved.

Answer (score 2):

The statement $\Gamma\vDash \phi$ has the meaning "in all models where the formulas in $\Gamma$ are true, also the formula $\phi$ is true."

If we want to show that $\Gamma\vDash\phi$, two methods seem reasonable:

1. If we show that $\phi$ is a direct consequence of (some of) the formulas in $\Gamma$, then we have proved that $\Gamma\vDash\phi$.
2. If we show that $\Gamma$ is insatisfiable, then we have *also* proved that $\Gamma\vDash\phi$, since vacuously $\phi$ will hold in any model where $\Gamma$ holds.

Showing that $\Gamma$ is *satisfiable* only proves that the second method will not work. So, although it is perhaps helpful to know that there exist models of $\Gamma$, it does not help in any way to show that $\Gamma\vDash\phi$.

---

In fact, showing that $\Gamma$ is satisfiable can be very hard or even impossible. Take for example a set $\Gamma$ that contains a lot of formulas, as well as $\phi$ itself. Then $\Gamma\vDash\phi$, since $\phi\vDash\phi$. But, finding out if $\Gamma$ is satisfiable will take a lot more effort.

In first-order logic, Gödel's Second Incompleteness Theorem shows that no set of formulas that is strong enough to formulate arithmetic in (for example the set of axioms for Peano Arithmetic) can prove its own consistency. What this means, is that such a set of axioms *might* be satisfiable, but it is impossible to prove it (within the system itself).

But even if we just look at propositional logic, the task of determining whether a set of formulas is satisfiable is computationally *very difficult*, and cannot be done efficiently (as far as we know). In fact, it is an archetype of a difficult problem, know as the [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) problem.

Comment: Why does than an axiomatic system for mathematics (strong enough) exist if anything can be a logical consequence of this axiomatic system? (sorry if it is a stupid question but I am just a beginner in logic - I know just a propositional logic a bit now..)

Comment: @TKN Godel's incompleteness theorem forces us to do something like this: roughly, justifying the consistency of any "reasonable" set of axioms which can at least implement basic arithmetic requires more than that system itself. That said, we have options: ZFC, for example, is much stronger than we actually need for the vast majority of mathematics, and an inconsistency in ZFC wouldn't necessarily have any serious impact in math beyond logic since all the "usual" results go through in systems which have strictly weaker consistency strength than ZFC.

Comment: Incidentally, [reverse mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) studies exactly what axioms are needed to prove basic theorems of mathematics. So the question of exactly what we need to take for granted throughout mathematics is a well-studied one. If you like, you can think of all of mathematics as consisting of concrete results of the form "such-and-such theory proves such-and-such sentence;" an [extremely weak](https://mathoverflow.net/a/233881/8133) fragment of arithmetic is sufficient to perform a basic analysis of how such principles work.

Comment: @TKN Think of it like this: the rules of Peano Arithmetic are strong enough to prove interesting facts *about* natural numbers. We can do addition and multiplication, talk about prime numbers, polynomials, etc... However, we cannot show that the set of natural numbers itself actually exists within the rules of PA, since if it would exist, then it is a model for PA, and thus PA would prove its own consistency. We can prove the consistency of PA with a *stronger* set of axioms, such as ZFC. This last set is very strong, as Noah mentioned, so we can do almost all mathematics in it...

Comment: ... Except, we cannot show that ZFC itself is consistent: if we want to prove there is a model for ZFC,  we need yet again stronger assumptions. And so on, and so on. The good news is, that if we "believe" that ZFC is consistent, then we can use it to create proofs for almost anything you need in mathematics without any worries. This belief is at least partially justified since we have a lot of knowledge about the system, and have not found a single inconsistency.